# Google Apps - Unlimited account among Free accounts on the same domain?

Tags: google-workspace

Is it possible to upgrade only one account on a single Google Apps domain to the Unlimited (or 1TB since I have less than 5 users), $10/mo plan while keeping the other accounts (same domain) on the free version?  I'm running out of space with my 25GB on Drive and would like to have 1TB but don't want to pay for the other users to have 1TB when they don't even use it.

If that's not an option, is it possible to keep 1-2 users as the $5/mo plan while having mine at the $10/mo?

Also, would I be able to downgrade from the $10/mo plan to the free plan?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the individual account storage options?  Up to 30TB storage.

You may be able to purchase additional storage space per user without upgrading your entire Apps account.  Apps accounts are all at the same level, no mixing pricing.

View the details by opening your Google Account page. Log in with the account you want to increase storage for. (https://www.google.com/settings/storage if you only have one Google account signed in)

Top right corner of any Google page, click on your icon, then click on Account.

When your settings page opens, select "Data tools",
In the "Storage" box, select "Manage storage plan"

You should see the extra storage plan options there along with your current storage details.

To downgrade in the past, you had to first make sure your data storage usage was below the free threshold.

Remember, most anything you create with Docs, Sheets, or Slides won’t use up any of your storage.